# How to import javascript node module in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, npm-install

I am trying to import `xml2js` module , but facing 404 error saying `xml2js` not found

```
import xml2js from 'xml2js';
```

How to import JavaScript modules present in `node_modules` directory in TypeScript?

Comment: If you are using Angular-Cli you can check answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42410531/xml-data-parsing-in-angular-2/45067926#45067926

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference path

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/xml2jse/xml2js.d.ts" />
import xml2js = require("xml2js");
```

Remember you need to have a typescript module of xml2js

```
tsd install xml2js
```

Comment: Can't we use javascript module?

Comment: If you are using webpack... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525027/importing-js-file-into-typescript

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install or at least write a Module declaration.  Here is the declaration file on definitely typed: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/xml2js/xml2js.d.ts

You can install these module declarations with typings.
https://github.com/typings/typings

On declaration files:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html

You can also write your own module declarations but I recommend to look first in the registries. TypeScript will not understand any module without a declaration file.

Hope that helps ;)