# XML data parsing in angular 2

Tags: xml, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

Im new to angularjs2 and typescript,in my project i have a string variable comtaining xml as string, i need to process the string and access the data in the string according to node in the XML.Im having tough time by googling.Please help me out.

```
<groupDirectory>
<directoryDetails>
 <userId>extn5001</userId>
 <firstName>Park</firstName>
 <lastName>1</lastName>
 <groupId>communications</groupId>
 <extension>5001</extension>
</directoryDetails>
<directoryDetails>
 <userId>Yealinkt27ptest</userId>
 <firstName>Yealink T</firstName>
 <lastName>27P</lastName>
 <groupId>communications</groupId>
 <extension>4676</extension>
</directoryDetails>
<groupDirectory>
```

this is the xml i need to process.i need to access data according to nodes eg:name from

Answer (score 1):

By today, the suggested code in other answer (which suggests node-xml2js) didn´t work.
Instead of:

```
let parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
```

I used:

```
import { parseString } from 'xml2js';
```

The remaining part was ok.
Angular-cli used.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to bootstrap your application - next xml parser comes already with project installation.

https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js

So you do not need to add extra modules for this. As it is classic commonJS module - you need use `require` to import it:

```
let parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
```

So your code can looks like:

```
let parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
let xml = "<root>Hello xml2js!</root>"

parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
  console.dir(result);
});
```

You will receive next output:

[image]

In any cases - if you even do not use angular-cli or want to use your preferred module to parse xml - use `require` to load it.

Comment: use `var` instead of `let` then. You do not use typescript/es6 in your project?

Comment: ya i got it...i have another doubt how can i access data from the nodes

Comment: can u help me to access values from the nodes in xml

Comment: I have XML like this 

<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>

Got JSON like this

{"note":{"to":["Tove"],"from":["Jani"],"heading":["Reminder"],"body":["Don't forget me this weekend!"]}}